# Convert Enum into underlying type

Tags: f#

I have an enum as follows

```
type Suit =
    |Clubs = 'C'
    |Spades = 'S'
    |Hearts = 'H'
    |Diamonds = 'D'
```

How do I get the underlying char value if given enum value? 
eg I have `Suit.Clubs` and want to get 'C'

Comment: `let ch = (box suit) :?> char` seems to work, but I hope there's a more elegant solution that doesn't involve boxing...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

as another option

```
type Suit =
    |Clubs = 'C'
    |Spades = 'S'
    |Hearts = 'H'
    |Diamonds = 'D'

let c = Suit.Clubs
let v : char = LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue c
```

EDITED:
Comparison of different approaches:

```
type Suit =
    |Clubs = 'C'
    |Spades = 'S'
    |Hearts = 'H'
    |Diamonds = 'D'

let valueOf1 (e : Suit) = LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue e
let valueOf2 (e : Suit) = unbox<char> e
let valueOf3 (e : Suit) = (box e) :?> char
```

And under the hood:

```
.method public static 
    char valueOf1 (
        valuetype Program/Suit e
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 3 (0x3)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ret
} // end of method Program::valueOf1


.method public static 
    char valueOf2 (
        valuetype Program/Suit e
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2054
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: box Program/Suit
    IL_0007: unbox.any [mscorlib]System.Char
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method Program::valueOf2

.method public static 
    char valueOf3 (
        valuetype Program/Suit e
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2064
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: box Program/Suit
    IL_0007: unbox.any [mscorlib]System.Char
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method Program::valueOf3
```

Comment: Is there any drawback to using `LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue`? E.g. does it use reflection internally?

Comment: Excellent, very comprehensive. +1

Answer (score 8):

You can use functions from the `LanguagePrimitives` module:

```
// Convert enum value to the underlying char value
let ch = LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue Suit.Clubs

// Convert the char value back to enum
let suit = LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue ch
```

**EDIT:** I didn't see these functions in my first answer attempt, so I first suggested using:

```
unbox<char> Suit.Clubs
```

This is shorter than what *ildjarn* suggests in a comment, but it has the same problem - there is no checking that you're actually converting to the right type. With `EnumToValue`, you cannot make this mistake, because it always returns the value of the right underlying type.

Comment: I was surprised when `let ch = char suit` didn't work; I had assumed that an explicit conversion operator to the underlying type was generated for enums.